# Intercepting Change Password in Windows - Showing our custom interface

Tags: active-directory, passwords, change-password

I've been trying to synchronize the profile passwords of a third party system with AD. The third party system has its user profiles stored in a database.

I initially tried of writing a password filter to get the password in clear text and updating it in the database. Later i learnt that it is extremely risky to mess with the internals.

Now i'm thinking to intercept some event like 'begin change password' and show my custom interface to change the password instead of the default one. I know i cant intercept Ctrl + Alt + Del. But can i intercept this change password event and suppress the default behavior?

I'm looking for a generic solution that works in all the editions of Windows XP, Windows Vista and Windows 7.

Thank you.

Comment: You know how to intercept Ctrl+Alt+Del? Do tell!

Comment: Never EVER try to intercept the Ctrl + Alt + Del key combination.

Comment: Sorry, missed out two important words. 'I know I CANT intercept..'. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On XP/Server2003, you'd probably have done this by writing some [GINA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphical_identification_and_authentication) extension/replacement for the [winlogon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winlogon) system.  ([Docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa380543(VS.85).aspx)).

From Vista, these mechanisms were [replaced](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/925520) by something called [ICredentialProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776042(VS.85).aspx).

(So I suspect you're out of luck for a generic solution).

Comment: Is this a supported way of doing it? Can i use managed code like C# to develop this or should i use C++?

Comment: Sorry, no idea.  I only know a little about the "secure desktop" (winlogon) from some work to make server-side GPU (Direct3D) not be confused by it.  Never actually needed to do any GINA-related stuff myself.